# Springboot JPA on Java 1.6 always gives me GenericJDBCException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I need to create a fat jar that can hit to database and save the obtained files into the directory in the server. The server can only run Java 6 (1.6). Thus, I created a spring project with this pom:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.app.newapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>fileprocessing</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>editformpemrek</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <tomcat.version>7.0.59</tomcat.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.4</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Then I make the main class to be like this to try:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class FormAssignmentApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("FormAssignmentApplication");

    @Autowired
    FormService service;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(FormAssignmentApplication.class)
                .run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(service.findAll());
    }
}
```

Here is my service:

```java
@Service
public class FormService {
    @Autowired
    FormRepository formRepo;
    
    public List<FormAssignment> findAll() {
        return formRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

And here is my repository:

```java
public interface FormRepository extends JpaRepository<FormAssignment, Long> {
    List<FormAssignment> findAll();
}
```

The model/entity/POJO has this shape:

```java
package com.bca.oasys.editformpemrek.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ASSIGNMENT_FORM")
public class FormAssignment {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    private String studentId;
    
    @Column(name = "submitted_file")
    private byte[] doc;

    public String getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(String studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    public byte[] getDoc() {
        return doc;
    }

    public void setDoc(byte[] doc) {
        this.doc = doc;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

In this case, `studentId` is not ID in the table.

I ran those kind of code (except the pom) at Java 8 properly, then I changed the dependencies to suit the Java 6, and I got this exception chain:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:310)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:221)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at $Proxy46.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.app.newapp.fileprocessing.service.FormService.findAll(FormService.java:22)
    at com.app.newapp.fileprocessing.FormAssignmentApplication.run(FormAssignmentApplication.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.runCommandLineRunners(SpringApplication.java:672)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2557)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1300)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:416)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:401)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:373)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.CharCommonAccessor.getBoolean(CharCommonAccessor.java:185)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarcharAccessor.getBoolean(T4CVarcharAccessor.java:794)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getBoolean(OracleResultSetImpl.java:640)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getBoolean(OracleResultSet.java:390)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BitTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(BitTypeDescriptor.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2969)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1696)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1628)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1515)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:726)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:921)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    ... 39 more
```

What should I do? Because I am quite new in Spring, and I didn't get any error in my IDE. While checking the stacktrace of error, I also stuck and can't find the root cause. I just see that it can't execute the `findAll` query, but I wonder which thing I had been wrong. I also had already put the database spec (conn string, username, and password) in `application.properties`. The thing is this code could run properly when I tried in java 8. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Spring Boot 1.2 doesn't support Java 16 or anything over Java 8. Also the `findAll` in your repository isn't needed, that is already part of the standard contract.

Comment: JDK 1.6 and 8 are both outdated and obsolete (especially 1.6), I recommend you use JDK 17.  Also use a recent springboot version.

Comment: @M.Deinum It was for Java 6, lower than Java 8.

Comment: @jewelsea I know it, but the java version on that server couldn't be upgraded because there are many legacy apps running there and not compatible with newer Java versions

Comment: Can’t you install another jdk to run your app separate from the existing jdk and apps, or use jpackage to include the modern jdk just with your app install not effecting the existing stuff?  I have never heard of a server that can only run Java 1.6.

Comment: If it has to be 1.6 then write the app totally old school using just jdbc and no spring of jpa.  Just a suggestion.

Comment: Well.. I don't have the rights to install anything there sadly, the server need to run Java 1.6 and I haven't ever heard that running 2 different Java version at a server at the same time is possible...

Comment: The `byte[]` field needs an `@Lob` annotation so it is treated as a proper blob.

Comment: `new SpringApplicationBuilder(FileProcApplication.class).run(args)` is it intentionally some unrelated class?

Comment: Hi @xerx593, It actually a mistyping on it, as you can see in the error stack trace, there was not any such error related to main class name. Regardless of that, thank you for the correction

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your suggestion, I tried your suggestion, but the exception still exists.

Comment: Then either your data type in the database isn't a blob or something else is amiss as it tries to convert something into a `Boolean` (see the stacktrace). So either your column is a bit/byte in the database instead of a Blob or you have a piece of configuration that is throwing things of (and that you aren't showing).

Comment: @M.Deinum Well, I don't know why it tried converting something to a Boolean. However I just think that Java 6 does not support the use of this JpaRepository. When I use the plain Dao, session, and hql query, it works fine.

Comment: If it wouldn't support it it wouldn't start. It can work perfectly fine with with JDK 1.6. Using a `Session` isn't using JPA, you should use an `EntityManager` to do the same. Also the conversion to the boolean comes from the mapping of the type to the database which is just JPA (or hibernate in this case) and has nothing to do with Spring Data JPA. The fact that your query works makes me wonder what you are actually executing as the query should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

`JpaRepository<FormAssignment, String>` - here you have mentioned that your primary key is of String type but in your entity class you have annotated the id Variable with `@id` which is of type `Long`. I think you have to update this to

```
JpaRepository<FormAssignment, Long>
```

Comment: Thank you for your correction, but even though I had already changed it to Long, it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

check column data types, in your DB, and entity datatypes. They must be same.

Comment: They are already same. I have tried all of this in Java 1.8 and it was okay

Comment: than check the versions